# How to switch view controller under this circumstance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that I need to refresh it self so, I basically reload it with the following code.

```
   -(void)check{
   GameController*myNewVC = [[GameController alloc] init];
   [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:NO];
     }
```

I can call the method above in gamecontroller and it works fine, but in a button sub class I use the method below and it doesn't work because nothing happens.

.h

```
  @interface CellButton : UIButton {
     }
```

.m

```
  GameController*myNewVC = [[GameController alloc] init];
       [myNewVC check];
```

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Why create a whole new view controller when you can just tell the one you've got to refresh itself?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work"

Comment: There is a function in the button class that will dictate weather or not the view controller will refresh it self. I rather keep it this way for organization reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a view controller that I need to refresh it self so, I basically reload it

**Don't do that.** Your view controller *isn't* refreshing itself, it's replacing itself, and it's hard to think of a reason that it should need to do that.

Put the code the loads the data in a separate method, and call that method on the existing view controller instead of creating a whole new view controller. For example, many view controllers that manage a UITableView will call the table's `-reloadData` method to tell the table to discard any cells that are currently visible and request new ones. No matter what kind of view(s) your view controller manages, you can do something similar.

> I can call the method above in gamecontroller and it works fine, but
>   in a button sub class I use the method below and it doesn't work
>   because nothing happens.

That's most likely because you say you're using the code in a UIButton subclass, and the code says:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:NO];
```

So, the button is telling itself to present the view controller. However, UIButton doesn't have a `presentModalViewController:animated:` method. I'm surprised that "nothing happens" -- I'd expect an exception due to the unimplemented method. It should work fine if you replace `self` above with a pointer to your view controller. Or, much better, put the code in an IBAction method in the view controller, set the buttons action to that method, and its target to the view controller.

(from your comment...)

> There is a function in the button class that will dictate weather or
>   not the view controller will refresh it self.

That sounds like a poor plan -- in a well designed MVC application, logic that controls whether the view controller will refresh belongs in the view controller. Have the view controller enable/disable or show/hide the button based on whatever conditions control the refreshing behavior.

Comment: Just to be clear, the controller I am refreshing will load it self.As if someone hooked a push button in a view controller to itself.